# Flask-SQLAlchemy join across 3 models and a Table construct

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have 3 models:

```
class Customer(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    statemented_branch_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('branch'))
    ...

class Branch(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'branch'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

class SalesManager(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_manager'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    branches = relationship('Branch', secondary=sales_manager_branches)
```

And a Table construct:

```
sales_manager_branches = db.Table(
    'sales_manager_branches',
    Column('branch_id', Integer, ForeignKey('branch.id')),
    Column('sales_manager_id', Integer, ForeignKey('sales_manager.id'))
)
```

I want to be able to get all `Customers` for a `SalesManager`, which means all Customers that have a `statemented_branch_id` in any of the `Branch`es the `SalesManager.branches` relationship.

My query is looking something a little like this:

```
branch_alias = aliased(Branch)
custs = Customer.query.join(branch_alias, SalesManager.branches).\
        filter(Customer.statemented_branch_id == branch_alias.id)
```

Which is obviously not right.

How can I get all `Customers` for a `SalesManager`?

**Update**

When I try:

```
Customer.query.\
         join(Branch).\
         join(SalesManager.branches).\
         filter(SalesManager.id == 1).all()
```

I get an OperationalError:

```
*** OperationalError: (OperationalError) ambiguous column name: branch.id u'SELECT
customer.id AS customer_id, customer.statemented_branch_id AS 
customer_statemented_branch_id \nFROM customer JOIN branch ON branch.id 
customer.statemented_branch_id, "SalesManager" JOIN sales_manager_branches AS 
sales_manager_branches_1 ON "SalesManager".id = sales_manager_branches_1.sdm_id JOIN 
branch ON branch.id = sales_manager_branches_1.branch_id \nWHERE "SalesManager".id = ?'
(1,)
```

Comment: You'll need to `aliased` `Branch` for you join in this case as SQLAlchemy is putting the `branch` table into the SQL twice, and both times without aliases.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I ended up doing it like in my answer below. I've up-voted your answer / comments, but I'll accept my own when I can.

Answer (score 8):

I needed to add a `backref` to my `SalesManager` model that allows SQLAlchemy to figure out how to get from `SalesManager` to branch.

```
class SalesManager(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_manager'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    branches = relationship(
        'Branch', secondary=sales_manager_branches, backref="salesmanagers")
```

And construct the query like this:

```
Customer.query.\
         join(Branch).\
         join(Branch.salesmanagers).\
         filter(SalesManager.id == 1).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SalesManager.query \
            .join(Branch) \
            .join(Customer) \
            .filter(SalesManager.id == 123)
```

You may need to provide explicit `on` params, via the second argument to `join`, or you may need to explicitly add the mapping table in - but in either case what you are trying to do is the following:

```
SELECT SM.*
FROM sales_manager SM
JOIN sales_manager_branches SMB
    ON SM.id = SMB.sales_manager_id
JOIN branch B
    ON SMB.branch_id = B.id
JOIN customer C
    ON B.id = C.statemented_branch_id
WHERE -- Conditions go here
```

Comment: This will return a list of `SalesManager`s, right? I want a list of `Customer`s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my question above with what's happening when I try this.